# Can´t read odata in mvc controller

Tags: odata, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following url:

```
http://localhost:64863/api/Entity/getStatus?%24skip=0&%24top=25&%24inlinecount=allpages&_=1473445898026
```

My question is how can I read **skip** and **top** in controller. This is my controller signature:

```
[HttpGet("getStatus")]
public JsonResult GetStatus(
    string filter, 
    int skip, 
    int top)
{
```

Comment: If your URL is `/getStatus?skip=0&top=25` instead of `/getStatus?%24skip=0&%24top=25`, then you should be able to read `skip` and `top` in your controller.

Comment: Yes, its true, but i can't change url, so what I need to make this work?

Comment: For the sake of helping other people who also read this question, which version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? I'd guess it's not MVC 5 or below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i added after get QueryString:

```
private string getParameterFromUrl(string parameter)
        {
            string url = Request.QueryString.Value;
            Match match = Regex.Match(url, parameter + "=([^&]*)");

            return match.Result("$1");
        }
```

Where parameter is **skip** or **top** in my case

Answer (score 0):

The following query string

```
%24skip=0&%24top=25
```

will be available in `Request.QueryString` with the following keys: `$skip` and `$top`. You won't be able to change your controller parameter names to `$skip` and `$top` since you'll get an error in Visual Studio and won't be able to compile, so you can remove the `skip` and `top` parameter and get the `%24skip` and `%24top` values from `Request.QueryString` in your controller

```
[HttpGet("getStatus")]
public JsonResult GetStatus(
    string filter)
{
    string skip = string.Empty;
    string top = string.Empty;

    if (Request.QueryString["$skip"] != null)
    {
        skip = Request.QueryString["$skip"];
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["$top"] != null)
    {
        top = Request.QueryString["$top"];
    }

    // do whatever you want with skip and top variable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm getting the following error: "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'QueryString'".

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC controller or ASP.NET Web Api controller?

Comment: It is ASP.NET MVC controller

Comment: I used regex to read QueryString instead of [] xD Thank you for your help